# Float XML Namespaces to Root?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, namespaces

I have XML within a C# program that looks something like this:

```
<el1 xmlns="http://URI1">
    <el2 xmlns:namespace2="http://URI2"></el2>
    <el3>
        <el4 xmlns:namespace3="http://URI3"></el4>
    </el3>
</el1>
```

For cleanliness, I would like to move all the namespace declarations to the root element. I cannot change the export that produces this XML, so a solution needs to work on the sample as shown above. What is a good way to accomplish this?

This example is stripped down for brevity, but assume that there are further child elements that actually use these prefixes. These are irrelevant for this question as all the namespace prefix declarations are unique and my goal is only to move them higher in the tree.

I've reviewed the MSDN documentation for XML but there doesn't seem to be a simple way to manipulate namespaces like this. One of the solutions I've tried is interacting with the XML as an XElement and collecting the namespaces based on XAttribute.IsNamespaceDeclaration, replacing each element with its local name and finally creating a new root element with the collected list of namespace XAttributes. That line of experimentation caused a bunch of errors about redefining prefixes, though, and I'm not sure if I'm moving in the right direction or not.

Comment: *For cleanliness, I would like to move all the namespace declarations to the root element... and I'm not sure if I'm moving in the right direction or not*     There is nothing cleaner about prefixes being declared on the root element.   Pursuit of this goal has no right direction.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear. It's not purely for aesthetics, I need to eventually pass it to a web service that, for whatever reason, needs the namespaces declared in the root element. The goal I have described is the necessary goal in my context.

Comment: Then the web service is broken.  The right direction is to insist that they fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a prefix

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            El1 el1 = new El1()
            {
                el2 = new El2()
                {
                    el3 = new El3() {
                        el4 = new El4() {
                        }

                    }
                }
            };

            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("u4", "http://URI4");
            ns.Add("u3", "http://URI3");
            ns.Add("u2", "http://URI2");
            ns.Add("", "http://URI1");

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(El1));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, el1, ns);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("el1", Namespace = "http://URI1")]
    public class El1
    {
        [XmlElement("el2", Namespace = "http://URI2")]
        public El2 el2 { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("el2")]
    public class El2
    {
        [XmlElement("el3", Namespace = "http://URI3")]
        public El3 el3 { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("el3", Namespace = "http://URI3")]
    public class El3
    {
        [XmlElement("el4", Namespace = "http://URI4")]
        public El4 el4 { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("el4", Namespace = "http://URI1")]
    public class El4
    {
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can locate all the xmls attributes using the `namespace` xpath axis. Add those attributes to the root element. Finally write out the xml using `NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates`, which will leave the namespace declarations on the root and remove them from all the other elements.

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

// Find all xmlns: attributes
var attributes = xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//namespace::*");

// Add xmlns: attributes to the root
foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in attributes)
    xml.DocumentElement.SetAttribute(attribute.Name, attribute.Value);

// Write out results, ignoring duplicate xmlns: attributes
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates;
settings.Indent = true;

using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("XMLFile2.xml", settings))
{
    xml.Save(writer);
}
```